# Python and Javascript Pseudo Random Number Generator PRNG

Tags: javascript, python, random

I am looking for a way to generate the same sequence of pseudo random integer numbers from both python and javascript.

When I seed in python like this I get the below results:

```
random.seed(3909461935)   
random.randint(0, 2147483647) = 162048056
random.randint(0, 2147483647) = 489743869
random.randint(0, 2147483647) = 1561110296
```

I need the same sequence in javascript.

- Note: I used 2147483647 as the range in the randint method because I am assuming javascript can only handle 32 bit INTs.

Are there any libraries on both sides I can use to generate the same set of pseudo random numbers given the same seed?

Comment: Implement your own PRNG.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I don't want to re-invent when there has to be others that have solved this problem.

Comment: There are PRNG algorithms that are implemented in both Python and JavaScript, but you will have to do the searching by yourself. Look up a specific algorithm that you want to use and see if there are libraries for JS and Python.

Comment: They are very likely using different pseudo random algorithms.  As Derek said, implement your own.  A google search will show you some easy to implement algorithms.

Comment: @Dave The python documentation says that python's random uses the Mersenne Twister to generate 53 bit floating numbers. I tried a few javascript "Mersenne Twister" libraries with no luck. The outputs do not match.

Comment: A garden-variety linear congruential generator is just a few lines of code and more than adequate for most casual uses. That would be the easiest way to get sequences which can be easily reproduced in both languages.

Answer (score 3):

I have found two implementations of Mersenne Twister that generate the same 32 bit integer values given the same seed.

This way you can generate a server side sequence in Python, and have the browser independently generate the same sequence in javascript.

Python:

```
from mt_random import *
r = mersenne_rng(seed = 12345)
r.get_random_number() # Prints 3992670690
r.get_random_number() # Prints 3823185381
r.get_random_number() # Prints 1358822685
```

Javascript:

```
r = new MersenneTwister();
r.init_genrand(12345);
r = mersenne_rng(seed = 12345)
r.genrand_int32(); # Prints 3992670690
r.genrand_int32(); # Prints 3823185381
r.genrand_int32(); # Prints 1358822685
```

The JS is [here](https://github.com/neetsdkasu/mt19937ar-MersenneTwister-JS/blob/master/mt19937ar.js):

```js
/*
 *  疑似乱数生成機  移植  
 * 
 *  Mersenne Twister with improved initialization (2002)
 *  http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/mt.html
 *  http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/mt19937ar.html
 */
// = 移植元ラインセンス =======================================================
// ======================================================================
/* 
   A C-program for MT19937, with initialization improved 2002/2/10.
   Coded by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.
   This is a faster version by taking Shawn Cokus's optimization,
   Matthe Bellew's simplification, Isaku Wada's real version.
   Before using, initialize the state by using init_genrand(seed) 
   or init_by_array(init_key, key_length).
   Copyright (C) 1997 - 2002, Makoto Matsumoto and Takuji Nishimura,
   All rights reserved.                          
   Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
   are met:
     1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
     2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
        documentation and/or another materials provided with the distribution.
     3. The names of its contributors may not be used to endorse or promote 
        products derived from this software without specific prior written 
        permission.
   THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
   "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
   LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
   A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
   CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
   EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
   PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
   PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
   NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
   SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
   Any feedback is very welcome.
   http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html
   email: m-mat @ math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp (remove space)
*/
// ======================================================================

function  MersenneTwister() {

    // 整数を扱うクラス
    function Int32(value) {
        var bits = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var i;
        var v = value;
        if (v != 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
               bits[i] = v & 0xff;
               v = v >> 8;
            }
        }
        this.getValue = function () {
            return (bits[0] | (bits[1] << 8) | (bits[2] << 16)) + ((bits[3] << 16) * 0x100);
        };
        this.getBits = function (i) { return bits[i & 3]; };
        this.setBits = function (i, val) { return (bits[i & 3] = val & 0xff); };
        this.add = function (another) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var i, fl = 0, b;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                b = bits[i] + another.getBits(i) + fl;
                tmp.setBits(i, b);
                fl = b >> 8;
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.sub = function (another) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var bb = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                bb[i] = bits[i] - another.getBits(i);
                if ((i > 0) && (bb[i - 1] < 0)) {
                    --bb[i];
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, bb[i]);
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.mul = function (another) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var bb = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                for (j = 0; i + j < 4; ++j) {
                    bb[i + j] += bits[i] * another.getBits(j);
                }
                tmp.setBits(i, bb[i]);
                bb[i + 1] += bb[i] >> 8;
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.and = function (another) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, bits[i] & another.getBits(i));
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.or = function (another) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, bits[i] | another.getBits(i));
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.xor = function (another) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, bits[i] ^ another.getBits(i));
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.rshifta = function (s) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var bb = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var p = s >> 3;
            var i, sg = 0;
            if ((bits[3] & 0x80) > 0) {
                bb[4] = sg = 0xff;
            }
            for (i = 0; i + p < 4; ++i) {
                bb[i] = bits[i + p];
            }
            for (; i < 4; ++i) {
                bb[i] = sg;
            }
            p = s & 0x7;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, ((bb[i] | (bb[i + 1] << 8)) >> p) & 0xff);
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.rshiftl = function (s) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var bb = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var p = s >> 3;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i + p < 4; ++i) {
                bb[i] = bits[i + p];
            }
            p = s & 0x7;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, ((bb[i] | (bb[i + 1] << 8)) >> p) & 0xff);
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.lshift = function (s) {
            var tmp = new Int32(0);
            var bb = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var p = s >> 3;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i + p < 4; ++i) {
                bb[i + p + 1] = bits[i];
            }
            p = s & 0x7;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                tmp.setBits(i, (((bb[i] | (bb[i + 1] << 8)) << p) >> 8) & 0xff);
            }
            return tmp;
        };
        this.equals = function (another) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                if (bits[i] != another.getBits(i)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
        this.compare = function (another) {
            var i;
            for (i = 3; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (bits[i] > another.getBits(i)) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (bits[i] < another.getBits(i)) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }
    // End of Int32
    
    
    /* Period parameters */
    var N = 624;
    var M = 397;
    var MATRIX_A = new Int32(0x9908b0df); /* constant vector a */
    var UMASK = new Int32(0x80000000); /* most significant w-r bits */
    var LMASK = new Int32(0x7fffffff); /* least significant r bits */
    
    var INT32_ZERO = new Int32(0);
    var INT32_ONE = new Int32(1);
    
    var MIXBITS = function (u, v) {
        return (u.and(UMASK)).or(v.and(LMASK));
    };
    var TWIST = function (u, v) {
        return ((MIXBITS(u, v).rshiftl(1)).xor((v.and(INT32_ONE)).equals(INT32_ZERO) ? INT32_ZERO : MATRIX_A));
    };
    
    var state = new Array(); /* the array for the state vector  */
    var left = 1;
    var initf = 0;
    var next = 0;
    
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        state[i] = INT32_ZERO;
    }
    
    /* initializes state[N] with a seed */
    var _init_genrand = function (s) {
        var lt1812433253 = new Int32(1812433253);
        var j;
        state[0]= new Int32(s);
        for (j = 1; j < N; ++j) {
            state[j] = ((lt1812433253.mul(state[j - 1].xor(state[j - 1].rshiftl(30)))).add(new Int32(j))); 
            /* See Knuth TAOCP Vol2. 3rd Ed. P.106 for multiplier. */
            /* In the previous versions, MSBs of the seed affect   */
            /* only MSBs of the array state[].                        */
            /* 2002/01/09 modified by Makoto Matsumoto             */
            //state[j] &= 0xffffffff;  /* for >32 bit machines */
        }
        left = 1; initf = 1;
    };
    this.init_genrand = _init_genrand;
    
    /* initialize by an array with array-length */
    /* init_key is the array for initializing keys */
    /* key_length is its length */
    /* slight change for C++, 2004/2/26 */
    this.init_by_array = function (init_key, key_length) {
        var lt1664525 = new Int32(1664525);
        var lt1566083941 = new Int32(1566083941);
        var i, j, k;
        _init_genrand(19650218);
        i = 1; j = 0;
        k = (N > key_length ? N : key_length);
        for (; k; --k) {
            state[i] = ((state[i].xor((state[i - 1].xor(state[i - 1].rshiftl(30))).mul(lt1664525))).add(
              new Int32(init_key[j]))).add(new Int32(j)); /* non linear */
            //state[i] &= 0xffffffff; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
            i++; j++;
            if (i >= N) { 
                state[0] = state[N - 1];
                i = 1; 
            }
            if (j >= key_length) {
                j = 0; 
            }
        }
        for (k = N - 1; k; --k) {
            state[i] = (state[i].xor((state[i-1].xor(state[i - 1].rshiftl(30))).mul(lt1566083941))).sub(
              new Int32(i)); /* non linear */
            //state[i] &= 0xffffffff; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
            i++;
            if (i >= N) {
                state[0] = state[N - 1]; 
                i = 1; 
            }
        }
    
        state[0] = new Int32(0x80000000); /* MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array */ 
        left = 1; initf = 1;
    };
    
    var next_state = function () {
        var p = 0;
        var j;
    
        /* if init_genrand() has not been called, */
        /* a default initial seed is used         */
        if (initf == 0) {
            _init_genrand(5489);
        }
    
        left = N;
        next = 0;
        
        for (j = N - M + 1; --j; ++p) {
            state[p] = state[p + M].xor(TWIST(state[p], state[p + 1]));
        }
        
        for (j = M; --j; ++p) {
            state[p] = state[p + M - N].xor(TWIST(state[p], state[p + 1]));
        }
    
        state[p] = state[p + M - N].xor(TWIST(state[p], state[0]));
    };

    var lt0x9d2c5680 = new Int32(0x9d2c5680);
    var lt0xefc60000 = new Int32(0xefc60000);

    /* generates a random number on [0,0xffffffff]-interval */
    var _genrand_int32 = function () {
        var y;
    
        if (--left == 0) {
            next_state();
        }
        
        y = state[next];
        ++next;
    
        /* Tempering */
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(11));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(7)).and(lt0x9d2c5680));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(15)).and(lt0xefc60000));
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(18));
    
        return y.getValue();
    };
    this.genrand_int32 = _genrand_int32;

    /* generates a random number on [0,0x7fffffff]-interval */
    this.genrand_int31 = function () {
        var y;
    
        if (--left == 0) {
            next_state();
        }
        y = state[next];
        ++next;
    
        /* Tempering */
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(11));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(7)).and(lt0x9d2c5680));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(15)).and(lt0xefc60000));
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(18));
    
        return (y.rshiftl(1)).getValue();
    };
    
    
    /* generates a random number on [0,1]-real-interval */
    this.genrand_real1 = function () {
        var y;
    
        if (--left == 0) {
            next_state();
        }
        y = state[next];
        ++next;
    
        /* Tempering */
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(11));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(7)).and(lt0x9d2c5680));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(15)).and(lt0xefc60000));
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(18));
    
        return y.getValue() * (1.0/4294967295.0); 
        /* divided by 2^32-1 */ 
    };
    
    /* generates a random number on [0,1)-real-interval */
    this.genrand_real2 = function () {
        var y;
    
        if (--left == 0) {
            next_state();
        }
        y = state[next];
        ++next;
    
        /* Tempering */
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(11));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(7)).and(lt0x9d2c5680));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(15)).and(lt0xefc60000));
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(18));
    
        return y.getValue() * (1.0 / 4294967296.0); 
        /* divided by 2^32 */
    };

    /* generates a random number on (0,1)-real-interval */
    this.genrand_real3 = function () {
        var y;
    
        if (--left == 0) {
            next_state();
        }
        y = state[next];
        ++next;
    
        /* Tempering */
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(11));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(7)).and(lt0x9d2c5680));
        y = y.xor((y.lshift(15)).and(lt0xefc60000));
        y = y.xor(y.rshiftl(18));
    
        return (y.getValue() + 0.5) * (1.0 / 4294967296.0); 
        /* divided by 2^32 */
    };

    /* generates a random number on [0,1) with 53-bit resolution*/
    this.genrand_res53 = function () {
        var a = ((new Int32(_genrand_int32())).rshiftl(5)).getValue();
        var b = ((new Int32(_genrand_int32())).rshiftl(6)).getValue(); 
        return (a * 67108864.0 + b) * (1.0 / 9007199254740992.0); 
    };
    /* These real versions are due to Isaku Wada, 2002/01/09 added */

}
```

The corresponding Python implementation is [here](https://github.com/james727/MTP/blob/master/mersenne_twister.py):

```js
class mersenne_rng(object):
    def __init__(self, seed = 5489):
        self.state = [0]*624
        self.f = 1812433253
        self.m = 397
        self.u = 11
        self.s = 7
        self.b = 0x9D2C5680
        self.t = 15
        self.c = 0xEFC60000
        self.l = 18
        self.index = 624
        self.lower_mask = (1<<31)-1
        self.upper_mask = 1<<31

        # update state
        self.state[0] = seed
        for i in range(1,624):
            self.state[i] = self.int_32(self.f*(self.state[i-1]^(self.state[i-1]>>30)) + i)

    def twist(self):
        for i in range(624):
            temp = self.int_32((self.state[i]&self.upper_mask)+(self.state[(i+1)%624]&self.lower_mask))
            temp_shift = temp>>1
            if temp%2 != 0:
                temp_shift = temp_shift^0x9908b0df
            self.state[i] = self.state[(i+self.m)%624]^temp_shift
        self.index = 0

    def get_random_number(self):
        if self.index >= 624:
            self.twist()
        y = self.state[self.index]
        y = y^(y>>self.u)
        y = y^((y<<self.s)&self.b)
        y = y^((y<<self.t)&self.c)
        y = y^(y>>self.l)
        self.index+=1
        return self.int_32(y)

    def int_32(self, number):
        return int(0xFFFFFFFF & number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rng = mersenne_rng(1131464071)
    for i in range(10):
        print rng.get_random_number()
```